# Svelte UI not updated despite data change

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to have button toggle a drawer component to open/close.

**I have a simplified example in this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6404fc40b48e4b91874feada817ff446?version=3.44.3)**

I am currently using a module context that exports a function so the the parent of both components can call it. The function is called, data is updated, but the UI won't react to this.

What am I (not) doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop the `context="module"` part you can export the function as a variable and use `bind:toggleSomeComp` on the parent.

Example:

```html
<!-- SomeComp.svelte -->
<script>
    let isOpen = false;
    export const toggleSomeComp = () => {
        isOpen = !isOpen;
        console.log('toggle called, isOpen now = ', isOpen);
    }
</script>

<hr/>
someComp isOpen? -> {isOpen}
```

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import Button from './Button.svelte';
    import SomeComp from './SomeComp.svelte';
    let name = 'world';
    let toggleSomeComp;
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>

<Button on:clicked={() => toggleSomeComp()}>
    Button is sibling of SomeComp
</Button>

<SomeComp bind:toggleSomeComp></SomeComp>
```

Answer (score 1):

When sharing data across siblings through the `context="module"` like this you have to use a store.
So

```js
export let isOpen = writable(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't help you, make sure the path to the `bundle.js` file in the `public/index.html` file is correct. This was the issue in my case and changing that path to the most recently updated `build.js` file solved this issue for me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src='bundle/bundle.js'></script> <!-- Make sure this path is correct -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```